# Angular - Router UI - loading of abstract template not caught with $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, router

I have an abstract template (I use router-ui). After I click on a link that points to one of the "child" route, I can see two requests sent for two templates (ofcourse, it makes sense).

In our project, we intercept every state change with

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
```

and we append a token to every call to our template provider.

```
 if(toState.hasOwnProperty('templateUrl')){
      toState.templateUrl = PartialService.get(toState.templateUrl);
 }
```

It works just fine on every route except the abstract one. So when I click a link that points to a route that has it's abstract route, I intercept the call to the child, but not the abstract route, which means we don't append that token which I mentioned at start, and ofcourse, I get no response out of our tpl provider.

Anyone had any similiar problem?

Thank you!

Comment: anyone? still no luck with this .. :/

Answer (score 2):

This is from Ari Lerner's book: ng-book which I very highly recommend.
[ng-book](https://www.ng-book.com/)

An abstract template can never be directly activated, but can set up descendants that are
activated.

We can use an abstract template to provide a template wrapper around multiple named views,
or to pass $scope objects to descendant children. We can use them to pass around resolved
dependencies or custom data or simply to nest several routes under the same ‘url’ (e.g., have all
routes under the /admin URL).